# Remove the Extra white space below Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

I'm using below layout to populate my Fragment with ImageView and Textbox. But There is an Extra white space below the RelativeLayout which I am unable to wipe out.
[image]

How can I align the GridView with Relativelayout with no extra white space between?

and

How can I decrease the height  of Cardview??

Below my xml Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/rp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            app:orientation="horizontal"
            app:columnCount="2"
            android:background="#FEFEFE"
            app:rowCount="3"
            app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            >

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/eka"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id='@+id/eka'/>

                    <TextView
                       android:text="कान्तिपुर "
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/kat'
                        android:src="@drawable/kat"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Kathmandu Post"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/set'
                        android:src="@drawable/set"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="सेतोपाटि"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/rato'
                        android:src="@drawable/rat"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="रातोपाटि"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/gor'
                        android:src="@drawable/gor"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="गोर्खापत्र"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/bbc'
                        android:src="@drawable/bbc"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="BBC नेपाल"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/onl'
                        android:src="@drawable/onl"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Online खबर"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id='@+id/nag'
                        android:src="@drawable/nag"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="नागरिक"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#0f539c"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try decreasing `android:layout_margin="16dp"` and use only specific margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `android:weightSum="6"` to the complete LinearLayout. Therefore, the RelativeLayout makes up a sixth of the total height (`android:layout_weight="1"`). As your GridLayout is quite large (in relation to your FrameLayout) the FrameLayout becomes big, too (one fifth of the GridLayout to be exact). The image is not large enough to fill the entire FrameLayout and you see that extra space.

You shouldn't use weights in your case. Just assign `wrap_content` to both your RelativeLayout's and GridLayout's `android:layout_height`.

Here you can find further explanation about layout weights: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html